# CREATE TABLE error makes also an error in the implicit commit?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, commit, create-table

I know  that there are SQL statements that Cause an Implicit Commit, like create, alter, or drop. But does a CREATE TABLE error because the table is already created make an error in the implicit commit? I am working with Oracle11g in sql-developer.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it commits.

Why? Because that implicit commit happens **twice**: once before DDL, and once after it.

Therefore, here's what happens:

- implicit commit
- `CREATE TABLE` - which fails, as table already exists
- nothing happens afterwards because `CREATE TABLE` failed ...

  - .. but it doesn't affect what already has happened, and it was the 1st implicit commit